# What is $mA$, where $m \in \mathbb N$ and $A$ is a group?

Tags: group-theory, notation

Simple question. I was reading through a proof of Mordell's Theorem [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Ford.pdf), and in the statement of the Descent Theorem (page 4), the notation $A/mA$ is used, where $m \geq 2$ is an integer and $A$ is an abelian group. I have completely forgotten what $mA$ means in this case. I figure it is
$$mA = \{m \cdot x : x \in A\},$$
where $m \cdot x = \underbrace{x + x + \ldots + x}_{m\text{ times}}.$ Is this correct? (It certainly isn't $mA = \underbrace{A + A + \ldots + A}_{m\text{ times}}$, because then we would have $mA = A$.)

Comment: Yes, that’s correct; it’s a common notation when dealing with an Abelian group written additively.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks! If you write that as an answer I'll accept it. I just wanted to make sure that I had the right definition :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation of it is correct. The notation is quite common when dealing with an Abelian group written additively; the most familiar example is probably $m\Bbb Z$, the subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ consisting of the multiples of $m$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $A/nA$ is indeed quite common, and arises very often in the context of abelian groups. You gave an example in number theory, because the group of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ is finitely-generated abelian; another context is
in homological algebra. For example, for every abelian group $A$ we have $\mathbb{Z}/n\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A\cong A/nA$. This is important for the Tor functor. But, this is only a comment. The answer to your question is simply "yes".